# How do I make a static recursive method return a HashMap?

Tags: java, android, recursion

I am in the proces of creating a helper method that will allow me to traverse an XML document and put each element in a data HashMap and then return it. Here is the method I've been working on :

```
private static HashMap<String, String> traverseNodes( Node n, HashMap<String,String> data ) 
{
    NodeList children = n.getChildNodes();
    if( children != null ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++ ) {
        Node childNode = children.item( i );

        String nodeName = childNode.getNodeName();
        if(childNode instanceof Element)
        {
            data.put(nodeName, getStringByTag(nodeName, (Element)childNode));
            Log.d("traversal", childNode.getNodeName() + " was saved in hashmap");
        }


        else
            Log.d("traversal", childNode.getNodeName() + " Is not an Element type");

        System.out.println( "node name = " + childNode.getNodeName() );
        traverseNodes( childNode, data );
      }
    }

    return data;

}
```

I tried running the example and although I get messages saying that "childNode.getNodeName() + "was saved in hashmap". but the HashMap returned is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT! Bonus Question : I edited the code to reflect the changes suggested. It seems, however, that the method itself doesn't save the values of my XML Document. Are there any problems with the logic in the method ?*

Comment: You're creating a new HashMap for every invocation of the recursive method. Is that what you intended?

Comment: If so use `data.addAll(traverseNodes( childNode ));` as the recursive call. Not really efficient though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new map on each call. You need to pass the existing map *into* the recursive call. It should probably look like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> traverseNodes(Node n) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    traverseNodesRecurse(n, map);
    return map;
}

private static void traverseNodesRecurse(Node n, Map<String, String> map) {
    // Logic as per question
    // Recursive call (in the loop, etc)
    traverseNodes(childNode, map);

    // No need for a return statement
}
```

Comment: Yes but the OP's approach is potentially broken to start with. What if two elements in the tree have the same node name? Using a single `HashMap` will basically overwrite any entry which had the same `key`. No?

Comment: @Squonk: Yes, it would - but I'm assuming that was what the OP wanted. Put it this way - working out the key name (e.g. using the parent nodes and a dot notation) is a somewhat separate problem.

Comment: I know for a fact that no two elements are the same. However, my original idea was to have a HashMaps of HashMaps meaning that if(Node.hasChildNodes()) then I'd create a new HashMap. If not then simply assign the value of the node to the HashMap. How does that sound ? Basically having a tree of HashMaps mimicing the structure of the XML Document.

Comment: But you need the value as well as the children, don't you? You'd need a custom type to represent that, at which point you're going to end up reinventing the wheel... why not just use `Node` as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep `HashMap` outside the method and pass it as an argument -

```
private static HashMap<String, String> traverseNodes( Node n, HashMap<String, String> data  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that

```
private static HashMap<String, String> traverseNodes( Node n ) {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    traverseNodes( n, data );
    return data;
}

private static void traverseNodes( Node n, HashMap<String, String> data ) {
    // Here is your recursive code that do data.put(key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

private static traverseNodes( Node n) 
{
    NodeList children = n.getChildNodes();
    if( children != null ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++ ) {


        Node childNode = children.item( i );

        if(childNode instanceof Element)
        {

            String nodeName = childNode.getNodeName();
            data.put(nodeName, getStringByTag(nodeName, (Element)childNode));
            Log.d("traversal", childNode.getNodeName() + " was saved in hashmap");
        }


        else
            Log.d("traversal", childNode.getNodeName() + " Is not an Element type");

        System.out.println( "node name = " + childNode.getNodeName() );
        traverseNodes( childNode);
      }
    }

    return data;

}
```